# Github ssh-agent cannot push

Tags: git, ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

I want to Push changes via SSH to my git repo.

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have my ssh-agent up and running. I have my key loaded via `ssh-add`. It is the right key, I checked a bunch of times. It is also registered in my github.

When I try to `git push origin` I get the error from the above. It is the correct origin.

I also looked into this a lot and someone said that if you have multiple keys to the same git, it gets confused or something, but I have only one key loaded.

I cloned the repo via ssh aswell.

What should I do? I'm stuck on this for over 4 hours and I can't figure it out.

**UPDATE**

I've ran `ssh -v -T git@github.com` and the output is:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\s/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\s/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\s/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\s/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\s/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\s/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\s/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\s/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\s/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\s/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-b5f98373
debug1: no match: babeld-b5f98373
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:foobar
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\foobar/.ssh/known_hosts:1
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'foobar' to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:Ae2CCQzd33Dczv8gPiRiYEWJ7xwBVOU+719JTJ/5fjQ C:\\Users\\foobar\\.ssh\\foobar\\open_ssh-agent
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
warning: agent returned different signature type ssh-rsa (expected rsa-sha2-512)
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com (foobar).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi vivere! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2560, received 2468 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 10852.5, received 10462.5
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Try running `ssh -v -T git@github.com`. The "-v" option will cause ssh to print debugging output. Then [edit] your question to show the ssh command that you ran and the output.

Comment: @Kenster I ran it and apparently it authenticates me, but the exit code is still 1? I don't understand what's happening

Comment: @phd Can't run that, I'm on windows, but I've run: `'~' | Resolve-Path` in powershell and it shows: `C:\Users\s`. Also, `$env:HOMEPATH` in ps shows `\Users\s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ssh -Tv git@github.com does work, then check if you can contact the remote repo SSH URL with:

```
git ls-remote git@github.com:<me>/<myRepo>
```

Then compare that URL with the one registered in your local repository (`git remote -v`)
And if it is the same, check the output of `git config -l`: look for any directive with `insteadOf` in it, in case that URL would be changed by something else.

The [OP Vivere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14183155/vivere) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66373715/github-ssh-agent-cannot-push/66382821#comment117367652_66382821):

- Having to name the key as `id_rsa` and save it exactly in `~/.ssh`, following [this gist](https://gist.github.com/adamjohnson/5682757);
- Using the wrong `ssh-add.exe` (the one from OpenSSH)

Basically:

- don't use Powershell
- use a CMD session where the PATH does not reference `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\`

Comment: I tried what you recommended but nothing unusual showed up. I managed to make it somehow work by following these instructions: [link](https://gist.github.com/adamjohnson/5682757). Basically, the only thing that I did differently was having the key named `id_rsa` and saved exactly in `~/.ssh`. I wanted to have multiple keys and have them in different directories inside the `~/.ssh` dir because I want to split my keys, each with their own purpose. I want to have one for Jenkins for example. From what I've encountered, that is not possible? It must be named `id_rsa`?

Comment: I believe this has to do something with the Windows OpenSSH.
`where ssh-add  |  C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh-add.exe 
 |  C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-add.exe`
Until now I've worked in Powershell and cmd and I kept writing ssh-add to add my custom-named keys and it didn't work. Then I tried with id_rsa naming, and that worked but I had to write the passphrase every single time which was annoying even though it was in ssh-add.
Apparently, in git bash, everything works as expected. I also found this thread: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1263 which looks promising.

Comment: @Vivere You can have multiple keys: you need a ~/.ssh/config to differentiate them. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66269477/6309 for example.

Comment: @Vivere I have included your comment in the answer, but my take is: don't use Powershell, use a CMD where the PATH does not reference `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH`

Comment: I have to do two things. One, create some script that starts the agent and adds the keys and two, move to Linux. It's so hard to do anything on Windows it's driving me crazy

Comment: @Vivere True. These days, WSL2 makes it easier to access a true Linux environment from Windows, though. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting these errors from VsCode, follow these steps.

1. [image]

   from these images, check the bottom-left account button (git-hub), Logout from there, and log in again. It will work
2. If it's not working, take the keychain access

[image]

delete the accounts which are showing there retry step.1

Thank you.